# Leetcode 101 DFS, why isn't my code passing all the test cases?

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, depth-first-search

I am trying to solve Leet Code problem [101. Symmetric Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/symmetric-tree/description/):

> Given the root of a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (i.e., symmetric around its center).

I actually expected my code to work, yet my code seems to always return False, for any test case.

Code:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution(object):
    def isSymmetric(self, root):
        holder_left = []
        holder_right = []
        def Traverse_left(current_node):
            holder_left.append(current_node)
            if current_node.left:
                Traverse_left(current_node.left)
            if current_node.right:
                Traverse_left(current_node.right)
        def Traverse_right(current_node):
            holder_right.append(current_node)
            if current_node.right:
                Traverse_right(current_node.right)
            if current_node.left:
                Traverse_right(current_node.left)
        Traverse_left(root)
        Traverse_right(root)
        if holder_left != holder_right:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two unrelated problems:

- Your code is storing Node references in the holder lists, and these are unique for each node, so the lists will never be considered equal. You should instead store the node *values*
- The code implements a pre-order visit of the subtrees, but such a traversal can be the *same* for differently shaped trees. For instance, both of these trees have the same pre-order traversal:

  ```
            1             1
           /             / \
          2             2   3
           \
            3
  ```

  There are several ways to make it work, but one is to *include* `None` values in the generated lists, to denote where the children are absent.

Here are your two inner functions with those corrections:

```
        def Traverse_left(current_node):
            holder_left.append(current_node and current_node.val)
            if current_node:
                Traverse_left(current_node.left)
                Traverse_left(current_node.right)

        def Traverse_right(current_node):
            holder_right.append(current_node and current_node.val)
            if current_node:
                Traverse_right(current_node.right)
                Traverse_right(current_node.left)
```

This way it will work.

#### Remarks

It is a pity that this needs O(n) auxiliary memory (for storing the lists). This can be easily resolved by using generator functions and comparing the yielded values. `zip` can be useful here.

Secondly, a construct like the following `if...else` block is an anti-pattern, because the boolean expression can be used itself as return value:

```
        if holder_left != holder_right:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

That should just be:

```
        return holder_left == holder_right
```

Finally, it is not common practice to name functions in PascalCase -- that is commonly reserved for class names.

With these remarks we get this code (requires Python 3! Choose that language option in Leet Code):

```
class Solution:
    def isSymmetric(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        def traverse_left(current_node):
            yield current_node and current_node.val
            if current_node:
                yield from traverse_left(current_node.left)
                yield from traverse_left(current_node.right)

        def traverse_right(current_node):
            yield current_node and current_node.val
            if current_node:
                yield from traverse_right(current_node.right)
                yield from traverse_right(current_node.left)
        
        return all(a == b for a, b in zip(traverse_left(root), traverse_right(root)))
```